# Repeated objects in Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, arrays, pagination, kaminari

I have an array of objects in my controller, paginated by Kaminari:

```
@pics = Pic.page(params[:page]).per(12).order(sort_column)
```

I render each new set of 12 pics on the same page with an AJAX request, for a manual infinite scroll effect. The `sort_column` bit sorts the pics according to `most_viewed` attribute within the object.

My problem - sometimes, when there are a number of pics with the same `most_viewed` attribute, - i.e. there are 10 images with "20" as their most_viewed value - I will get repeated objects when the new set of 12 is revealed with the AJAX request.

Here's an example of what I mean... I've clicked the "load more" (i've left it in to demonstrate), and there are objects repeated when the new batch loads.

[image: repeated objects on Kaminari]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to order on count AND another column (id would be the best), in this way SQL will returns a list that will not change (because right now SQL does not know what to do if X records have the same count). You can change `.order(sort_column)` to `.order("#{sort_column} ASC, id ASC")`, and it should work ;)

Comment: This worked! Problem solved... big thanks. How do I mark a comment as answering the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to order on count AND another column (`id` would be the best), in this way SQL will returns a list that will not change (because right now SQL does not know what to do if X records have the same count).

You can change `.order(sort_column)` to `.order("#{sort_column} ASC, id ASC")`, and it should work.